# How to get the complete SAMLResponse after the authentication is completed from IDP

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-saml

I want to get the complete SAML Response in order to verify the signature of the response.

I am using spring SAML extension and below code is only giving the SAML assertion but not the complete SAML response.

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();                             
SAMLCredential credential = (SAMLCredential) authentication.getCredentials();
Assertion assertion = credential.getAuthenticationAssertion();
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend default **SAMLAuthenticationProvider** and override authenticate method. Inside this method you can get the complete SAML Response as follows:

```
SAMLAuthenticationToken token = (SAMLAuthenticationToken) authentication;
SAMLMessageContext context = token.getCredentials();
 try {

            String assertion = XMLHelper.nodeToString(SAMLUtil.marshallMessage(context.getInboundMessage()));
            System.out.println(assertion);
        } catch (MessageEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

 When I was exploring the methods of Assertion interface, I found credential.getAuthenticationAssertion().getParent() method which gives the SAML response and works fine in my case.

Is that wrong way to do?

Comment: Ohh!! I was not aware of that. I already had a custom implementation SAMLAuthenticationProvider, so I went with that approach and replied to your question. But If your code is working fine, it is certainly the best way.